# How did this user gain association reputation without having any Q&A activity?

Tags: bug, association-bonus

[This user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4291038/stephan1001) offered a bonus on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27043534/how-can-i-make-phonegap-camera-images-with-target-width-and-height-bigger-than-6).

How did this user get association reputation without asking or answering any questions on any of the associated accounts? Is this a bug?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

The 'association bonus earnable' flag is stored on the Stack Exchange network profile, and is never cleared. **Even when the original account is deleted**.

The user must've had an account with 200+ reputation somewhere, but that account is now gone. The fact that they once upon a time had such an account is enough for them to earn the 100 point association bonus on any new SE account.

This is not a bug; clearly, the user has proven that they know how to use Stack Exchange site features, which is what the bonus is for.

There *is* the possibility for abuse, of course. In this case, the account is a [sock puppet account](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277920/how-did-this-user-gain-association-reputation-without-having-any-qa-activity/277921#comment122125_277921) that is trying to launder the association bonus. IIRC, developers can reset the flag on a case by case basis for such abuse; perhaps in the future the reset can be done by moderators.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! I understand now.

Comment: This is actually kind of a bug. That user is a sock puppet that I destroyed a while ago. They keep recreating their accounts and abusing the association bonus to launder bounties. Dealing with this now.

Comment: @BradLarson: interesting! I forgot about the 'destroyed abuser accounts' angle. Perhaps the accounts on other sites should be disassociated / deleted too just to kill off the avenue? May not work if the account is associated through email.

Comment: @BradLarson: in this case, the association bonus flag should just be cleared. Perhaps a developer can assist there.

Comment: @MartijnPieters - Yeah, I pinged the appropriate people for this. It's a problem with sock puppet accounts that get above a certain level. They then create accounts on other sites, get the association bonus there, and even if their SO account is torched they can recreate it and get the association bonus from the accounts SO mods can't remove. Not the first time this has happened. Annoying.

Comment: @BradLarson: sounds like it is time for a moderator-accessible 'reset association bonus flag' knob.

Comment: Sounds more like it's time for a "completely nuke and ban this user forever" button. Why does a user with a history of abuse still have any accounts on the SE network and why are they able to create a new one on SO even though the old one was deleted by a mod? At the very least, mods should have the power to forever ban the user from creating an account at their specific site. A function for simply deleting all of their existing SE accounts and blacklisting them so that they can never create another one would be preferable, but that's probably deemed too powerful for non-devs.

Comment: @MartijnPieters If I find an account that needs to be looked at due to this *association bonus feature* would a moderator flag be handled as helpful? iow do you want me to flag this kind of stuff?

Comment: @rene: if the account is suspicious, please do flag!

Comment: @rene: that's a different case; they are not using a pre-existing association bonus to re-join a site and resume sock activity.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Ok, so if you get the bonus due to serial upvotes the bonus is considered legit?

Comment: @rene: it is not something we usually pursue, no.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Is  it worth bringing it up on meta to get some public guidance on it?

Comment: @rene: if you must; the 100 points of the bonus is not something we can easily do anything about, is peanuts compared to what cheaters are after, and generally not worth our time worrying over, however.

Comment: What do the cheaters gain by doing this?

Comment: @Eric: I don't want to go into too many details, but for starters, socks recreated this way don't have to wait for their initial 15 points to be able to vote.