# Should the association bonus be reversed if it was obtained by serial voting?

Tags: discussion, serial-voting, association-bonus

I stumbled upon an account where the reputation history looked like this:

> [image: Association bonus and reversal]

Due to a barrage of serial upvotes the user received the Association bonus for crossing the 200 reputation mark. The voting reversal script detected (most) of the serial votes and corrected for that, hence the -70. It didn't reversed the association bonus though, effectively giving this user 100 rep based on a doubtful action.

There are some other posts about association bonuses get awarded in corner case situations, like:

- [How did this user gain association reputation without having any Q&A activity?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277920/how-did-this-user-gain-association-reputation-without-having-any-qa-activity)
- [Association Bonus not removed upon account deletion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/191415/association-bonus-not-removed-upon-account-deletion)
- [Why does this user have association bonus](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/233624/why-does-this-user-have-association-bonus)
- [Shouldn't the association bonus acquired via serial upvoting be reversed?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/215516/shouldnt-the-association-bonus-acquired-via-serial-upvoting-be-reversed) (cross-site dupe) <sup>1</sup>

but I couldn't find any post that describes/notices the above mentioned scenario. I had an exchange with a moderator (who shall remain anonymous because it was [Martijn Pieters](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/100297/martijn-pieters)) who handed me this advice:

> the 100 points of the bonus is not something we can easily do anything about, is peanuts compared to what cheaters are after, and generally not worth our time worrying over

... but that was after I already raised a moderator flag based on *if you find something suspicious, please flag*.

This post merely serves to be picked up when others search for this phenomenon  to get them decide if a flag is worth the effort. But feel free to share your thoughts if indeed this is considered peanuts and doesn't need handling (either by an enhancement in the voting reversal script or by flags from the community).

<sup>Thanks [gnat](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/839601/gnat)</sup>

Comment: That +100 is more than enough to vote for posts from other accounts, and create even more sock puppets.

Comment: Isn't the association bonus gained for having a certain amount of rep on *other* sites? So even if their rep has been removed here, they still (presumably) qualify for it?

Comment: @TZHX that is true but not in this case...the association bonus gained here is distributed across other SE accounts...

Comment: It leaves a bad taste for sure, but if I read the answer offered by he who should not be named (Martijn Pieters) in that first link, its a clear case of sh1te happens. But if this is the nature of the user in question, then I do believe that eventually enough misconduct will lead to more satisfying results. In other words: the problem will resolve itself.

Comment: @TZHX you get the bonus on all SE sites, _including the one that first broke 200 rep_.  So the bonus is wrong if the same site that broke 200 also had the serial voting.

Comment: @ryanyuyu agh... I didn't realise that. I thought it only applied to the *other* sites, sorry.

Comment: @S.L.Barth Only the main user of a sock network can keep the association bonus. For the sock puppets it doesn't matter as they're deleted anyway once discovered. And if a user abuses the association bonus to break some more rules they're very likely to just be outright deleted or suspended for a long time.

Comment: It seems this would be easily fixed by waiting to assign the association bonus until after the subroutine that reverses serial upvotes has run.

Comment: @WilliamKappler The association bonus is given as soon as you log in. It's not delayed until a later recalculation.

Comment: @WilliamKappler but that delay would prevent one of the main purposes of this bonus: Ability to sign in and do things. If i see wrong (or inexact) answer on site I technically never signed to, I want to comment immediately. If I'm made to wait, I'll probably go away and forget it.

Comment: @Mołot The delay could be added only to the first assignment of it - the one which is transferable to other sites. Basically, accounts are flagged as having that bonus. If they are, then when you get a new account, you get the bonus right away. However, to get the flag, you have to wait until after the serial upvote check. Seems common sense.

Comment: @WilliamKappler Really, it seems like a lot of unnecessary complexity to solve something that hasn't really been proven to be a problem.

Comment: @ChrisHayes It's not particularly complex, the system already works as I described as far as I can tell with the exception of when the bonus flag is set. Moving it to after the reversal would be trivial. Further, as S.L.Barth notes, there is a potential for exploitation.

Comment: @WilliamKappler There's no such thing as "trivial" when you're talking about someone else's codebase that you've never seen. And again, "potential" for exploitation isn't a high enough bar to change code that's working great 99.9% of the time.

Comment: @ChrisHayes Badges already work the way I suggest. If it's more than a few lines changed to implement, then there's probably bigger problems with how it is currently implemented.

Comment: I'm not sure how big of an issue this really is, but I wouldn't be surprised if now that it is clearly documented on meta, it becomes intentionally exploited. It's a flaw, I think most people would agree, it's just a matter of how big of a flaw vs. how complicated a fix. It *should not* be a complicated fix, but I can't know for sure - neither can anyone else know it's otherwise. Best I can do is offer a suggestion of how it might be fixed without affecting those who aren't exploiting it with what seems to be the minimal effort given the information available.