# User with three "User was removed" corrections

Tags: discussion, serial-voting, voting-fraud

I have come across a user who earned the `Mortarboard` badge the first day he gained reputation.

On the same day, I noticed there was a voting-abuse correction with ***"User was removed"*** and initially I thought to notify here to remove the badge (Is that important to remove a not deserved badge?) but then I investigated deeper and saw there were two ***"User was removed"*** that took respectively **10** and then **85** rep points.

There is always the possibility that these removed users are strange to him, but is it possible that these users are fake accounts created by himself? Theremust be taken some further actions than the vote-corrections?

Comment: Don't you think that the users being removed means the moderators are aware of what has happened, and have taken any actions they determine to be necessary?

Comment: related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/302340/should-the-association-bonus-be-reversed-if-it-was-obtained-by-serial-voting

Answer (score 6):

> Is it possible that these users are fake accounts created by himself?

Yes, it is *possible*. However, "User was removed" is also shown for totally innocuous situations, so it is also extremely *possible* the user has done nothing wrong.

> Must some further actions be taken than the vote-corrections?

**If** the user was removed for gaming the system, the account would have been removed by a moderator. The moderator would already have taken the necessary steps to warn the user, so there isn't any *further* action required from either other moderators or the community.

---

Lastly, please avoid pointing out specific users on meta in future. Focus on the behaviour, not the user.

Comment: Ok I understand! I thought tha the corrections was made by the background process and not by a moderator. To avoid any further downvote for the user I'm going to remove this question. Thank you!

Comment: @CliffBurton: That would be the ["Voting corrected"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/serial-voting-reversed) message, not "User was removed". However, even in this case, the damage has already been undone, so again, there's nothing further for the moderators or community to do.