# Why does the association bonus not count on protected questions?

Tags: support, reputation, protected-questions, association-bonus

I was browsing SO when I saw this line on a protected question:

> This question is protected to prevent "thanks!", "me too!", or spam answers by new users. To answer it, you must have earned at least 10 reputation on this site **(the association bonus does not count)**.

Why would the association bonus not count?

> If you are an experienced Stack Exchange network user with 200 or more reputation on at least one site, you will receive a starting +100 reputation bonus to get you past basic new user restrictions

Which means that the SE community has some trust in you to know your way around the network. This confuses me a little, since I would think that having experience on another network allows you to port that etiquette over to another platform.

I did some digging and some thinking, and have a couple of theories about this, but I wanted to know the community's take on this:

As described [in this other Meta question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/302340/should-the-association-bonus-be-reversed-if-it-was-obtained-by-serial-voting), the association bonus was awarded as a result of serial voting, a clear cheater. However, it seems a little excessive to protect against a (seemingly) sparse threat

I also came up with the idea that when joining a new community, there is a knowledge barrier, so answering questions with newbie information is less than ideal, and not counting the association bonus is to protect against that

Am I correct in my reasoning, or is there another explanation for ignoring the association bonus on protected questions?

Comment: I'd imagine it's because you get the association bonus no matter what you contribute just by joining a new site, so you don't necessarily have any idea on the new site of what may constitute a question that needs protected.

Comment: @patricksweeney Are there site-specific rules for protecting questions, however? From what I've seen, all discussions about protecting questions have been on meta.stackexchange, or blog posts - not relevant to particular sites. To me it seems the reasoning behind protecting a question is consistent across all sites.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

We on [Codegolf](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com) had the problem that a question got popular. It was shared first on the sideboard, then on HN and reddit, and attracted a lot of low quality posts.

The people who posted an answer had (most of the time) already an SO profile, but they did not know what was expected from them in an answer.

Self-regulation, like it is normally the case did not work:

- New users didn't see what a good answer should look like because there were a lot of bad answers.
- Regular users were busy downvoting/flagging/deleting the worst offenders.
- New users voted "funny" bad answers up, making moderation even harder.

(fwii: We want small explanations, not just code only answers)
Without protected questions such a flood from experienced SO users can't be handled.

The same thing happens here if a question is linked from HN/reddit.

Comment: Well, that case uses protection by the system or moderator, manual protection by high-rep users is too restricted...