# Serial voting was clearly only partially reversed - worth a mod flag?

Tags: discussion, voting, serial-voting

I've been wondering this for a while, since from time to time I look for users who have gained reputation in serial upvotes. Now, often times the automatic algorithm will have removed a small part of the so illicitly gained reputation already, but not most of it.

Usually I flag a serially upvoted post of the user with an explanation then. Usually my flags get accepted. But I wonder, is this something the moderators actually want to hear about or am I wasting moderator and CM time (IIRC, vote invalidations have to be escalated to a CM always) by being petty and nitpicky about reversals?

Here are some examples of what I'm talking about:

[image]

Here we can clearly see that all of the votes received between 10:13 and 10:14 were serial voting, in batches of 2 on each question, exactly to the rep cap for the day. Now, these were worth 200 reputation (300 with the association bonus, but AFAIK there isn't a mechanism for reversing it), but only 50 of those were reversed, leaving the user with a illicit gain of 150 (250) points for the activity.

[image]

Same here, we can clearly see that the votes were all received in a *very* short timespan (5:27 - 5:37, under 10 minutes total) on an account with otherwise very little vote activity, on at best neutral answers. Yet, only 150 of those 185 points got reversed.

Are these actions worth a mod flag? Or am I being petty and need to let it go?

Comment: If it is not a new bug then they came up with creative new ways to cheat.  Of course let a mod know about it.

Comment: Out of curiosity: How do you find users who have gained reputation through serial upvoting?

Comment: The association bonus case was raised by me earlier https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/302340/should-the-association-bonus-be-reversed-if-it-was-obtained-by-serial-voting and got a *meh* as response.

Comment: I got series of 4 downvotes on answers. I flagged for moderator attention, flag was marked as helpful but the votes were not rejected. I know it's just 4 votes, but it's actually -8 for Java gold badge and it's simply annoying :p Do mods revert such downvotes?

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, but I thought the association bonus was only applied to your own accounts when you join other communities. How do people get bonuses on other new accounts on the same site?

Comment: @SandPiper Association bonus is everywhere. Once per site, including the site you've earned it on

Comment: @BDL He uses SEDE queries, such as http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/708836/script-to-identify-unsual-vote-activity

Comment: @Magisch That's not what I meant. I think I am misunderstanding you. Are you saying that UserA is able to make a sockpuppet UserB and give that UserB an association bonus?

Comment: @xenteros same here: useful but no reversal...

Comment: @BDL Sorry for the late answer, but as Tyler said I use a couple of different SEDE queries and then manually check out the results.

Comment: My downvotes were reversed. Thanks mods!

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Do flag if you see this.

And as @Bhargav Rao points out in their [comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354835/serial-voting-was-clearly-only-partially-reversed-worth-a-mod-flag/354836?noredirect=1#comment502895_354836), if it is on your own account, you can use the "Contact us" link to have Stack Overflow (the company) handle it directly.

The serial voting detection script is good, but not perfect. Serial voters do find ways around it. And that is exactly why we have moderators - to be human exception handlers, to handle the cases that the system itself cannot.

I've been serially voted on myself a few times, both up and down. I've noted that some patterns that are easy to discern for humans, are hard to find for scripts.

Moderators do need to know it. We don't want people to get away with voting fraud.

You're not wasting the time of moderators, CM's or developers. Serial voting is often a case of voting fraud, which is one of the most serious breaches of our rules. And voting fraud is something that you cannot do accidentally.

Similarly, revenge downvoting is not something that should go unpunished. And serial upvoting, while presumably done for friendlier reasons, is also something we don't want.

So, continue to flag these cases.

Comment: I think I've read somewhere at meta that script is intentionally tuned to be conservative, in order to minimize false positives. From this perspective it makes perfect sense to flag suspicious cases that weren't caught by reversal script, so that moderators can use advanced tools to investigate or pass to SE team to check the issue at dev access level

Comment: @gnat Makes sense. Voting reversal is one situation where false positives will make users rightfully upset. Users who are acting in good faith, don't want the system to tell them they broke a primary rule.

Comment: To clarify, this wasn't me being voted on. I found other users with this reputation pattern

Comment: Yeah, agree with this answer. Voting fraud is something which we take seriously. Similarly, if you see that a revenge downvoting spree is only partially reversed, custom flag them, we'll escalate it. If it happens on your own account, then you can use the /contact page that is linked inside the "contact us" page at the bottom and escalate it yourselves. (It'd cut us middle men out).

Comment: @BhargavRao Is there a threshold at play for when you think this is a good use of the CMs time? Like, if 10 rep from the serial went unreversed, still flag or nah?

Comment: @Magisch Nopes, we usually don't have a threshold as such. There have been certain flags where users have explicitly mentioned, "19/20 upvotes were reversed, 1 upvote was not reversed, please revert that", which we have escalated to CMs. But in many of the cases, CMs have discovered that the other vote is usually from a different person and not from the person who serially upvoted. Hence, totally IMO, I feel that if it's just 1 or 2 upvotes that is not reversed, then there's not much use of involving CMs (again, it's just my opinion, not a "moderator rule" as such).

Comment: Those 1 or 2 extra votes could be from other, innocent users... or they could be from a (possibly undiscovered) sock puppet of the serial voter. Ordinary users cannot tell.

Comment: @S.L.Barth, even moderators can't see the individual downvotes, so we also can't tell. :) (we can only detect trends in voting, we can't see who voted where, hence any of the voting irregularities cases, have to be escalated).