# Old highly scored plagiarised answers don't result in reputation loss when deleted

Tags: discussion, feature-request, reputation, deleted-answers

I flagged an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54662236/difference-between-aws-dynamodb-vs-aws-documentdbnewly-launched-service/55015730#55015730)(10k+, score was +7/-0 if I remember rightly) for moderator deletion due to the source of the answer being plagiarised.

As a result of this the answer was deleted, however the user who posted the answer didn't lose the 70 reputation gained as a result of the votes because the post had [a score greater than 3 and had been on the site for more than 60 days](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5222/394554).

Should posts which are deleted for circumstances such as plagiarism result in the poster losing the gained reputation in the event that the post qualified for keeping that reputation change?

Comment: Is this a feature-request or just you want to discuss this?

Comment: Righto, didn't catch that part. Yeah, this would need intervention from CMs who I think have more important things to worry about than a few ill-gotten points.

Comment: You can add [meta-tag:bug] and [meta-tag:support] to be complete ... (j/k)

Comment: There are other cases where dubious activity gives you reputation gain that is not reversed, for example with [the association bonus](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/302340/should-the-association-bonus-be-reversed-if-it-was-obtained-by-serial-voting).

Answer (score 10):

This is a problem we face when presented with old plagiarised posts.

At the moment there's only two things we can do:

1. Ask the CMs for post disassociation. There are a couple of drawbacks with this. a) it's not what the processes is really aim at and b) it takes CM time away from doing other stuff.
2. Down-vote the post so it's scoring less than three and then delete. There's also drawbacks with this approach. The main one being that if the post is at +7 you'd need 5 down-votes to bring it's score down to a suitable level. Obviously we don't want to go around asking for down-votes on posts, though the -1 from the down-vote (assuming it's an answer) **is** returned once the post is deleted.

If you see a plagiarised post, then if it's not too highly scoring down-vote it before you flag. With the addition of the mod's down-vote (and perhaps one or two others along the way) it'll only be at +2 by the time it gets deleted.

*Please note, I'm **not** advocating coordinated voting here because that would be a bad thing.*

Comment: So adding a comment to the post with an explanation and link to the plagiarised source, downvoting and keeping an eye out on the post to see if it drops to 3 before flagging would be the best course of action (in the event I wanted the rep to be removed)?

Comment: You might not be advocating coordinated voting but it has that smell. At a minimum you're saying here that there is coordinated voting between the flagger and a mod. That makes them a voting mob.

Comment: @NickA ideally if you can, fix the post. Add in the attribution, but if it's just a copy/paste - add the comment, down-vote and flag at the same time. If the OP comes along and fixes the post then great we're all good. If not it'll get deleted even if the rep isn't removed.

Comment: @rene I'm not advocating coordinated voting. I'm pointing out that people should down-vote this sort of thing and that if they're worried about the -1 to their rep (because I know some people are) then they shouldn't be as that -1 will get returned when the post is deleted.