# My account on Stack Overflow has been deleted

Tags: support, moderation, deleted-users

Today's morning I opened my Stack Overflow account, and I came to know that there is no me on Stack Overflow. I thought this could be a mistake, so I clicked on "Join this Community" again. But by doing so, Stack Overflow created a new account with 101 reputation. And the weird behavior is the profile picture is the same as the previous one.

Here is the link of one of my answer.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/42943234

This is the screenshot of my previous account (mobile app):

[image]

I'm going to go mad.

Comment: .. and My name has been changed automatically. It is now Nevil Patel from Wizard.

Comment: @yivi What about the reputation I've earned?

Comment: You self-deleted, according to the account logs: *User: Nevil Patel (2756345) (Account.Id=3273652) deleted by Nevil Patel (2756345) Reason: self-deletion*

Comment: @MartijnPieters But I've never attempted to delete my account. Also my username wasn't `Nevil Patel`. It was `Wizard`.

Comment: That’s the account that wrote that answer. I suggest you go contact the community management team via https://stackoverflow.com/contact

Comment: Because that’s one of two emails registered  for your current account, as your login via Google. There is nothing we can do here. Talk to the CM team.

Comment: Put differently: the CM team can see much more than moderators in SO can see about your account and what may have happened. They are also the only ones that could possibly restore your account. The community here on Meta can’t do anything and can see even less as to what is going on. If you don’t have access to the pre-filled email address on the contact form, perhaps email team@stackexchange.com directly (that’s where the form info goes too).  Please be patient.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Sure, I'll contact the SO team. Thanks for your support.

Comment: _"You should care tackling the problem"_ - I'm sure **you** know more about this problem. Probably someone has access to your machine or your account on a shared machine, added their login to your account and requested deletion to annoy you. Yet you mention nothing of the sorts. Make sure you stay in control of your account. Stack Overflow themselves don't go around deleting random accounts.

Comment: The bit about the profile picture does seem weird

Comment: Well... you could say that some *wizardry* is taking place.

Comment: Something is disturbing. This question is asked by a deleted user while being one day old.

Comment: @Joshua yes, I'm suspecting something is up too, like perhaps there is a ban evasion or some other non-apparent precursor.

Comment: Didn't expect to stumble upon a non-fiction mystery on SO Meta so close to Halloween, but here we are. Chapter 2: done. Where does the story go from here? Stay tuned.

Answer (score 36):

Your old account was apparently self-deleted, according to the  log information moderators can see:

```
User was deleted on 10/22/2018 4:01:41 AM
User: Nevil Patel (2756345) (Account.Id=3273652) deleted by Nevil Patel (2756345)
Reason: self-deletion
```

and the [web archive copy from May 2018](http://web.archive.org/web/20180524104646/stackoverflow.com/users/2756345/wizard) confirms that the account at one point was named *Wizard*. Why it was renamed before deletion is not clear, we can't see the logs for that any more.

When you then logged in again using the same credentials as used for other accounts on the Stack Exchange network, a new Stack Overflow account was created for you, and your profile was copied over from one of those other accounts, where you used your full name instead of Wizard. You also received the association bonus of +100 points at this time (this is normal, see [How did this user gain association reputation without having any Q&A activity?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277920/how-did-this-user-gain-association-reputation-without-having-any-qa-activity)).

If you are sure the deletion process wasn't started by you, you'll need to check out [what logins you have registered](https://stackoverflow.com/users/mylogins/current); the page lists what account was last used when, and make sure to secure each account (change passwords, add 2FA if available, etc.). Self-deletion can only be initiated by your own account when logged in.

You'll need to contact the Community Managers team if you want to get more information on what happened, moderators can't see more than what I gave you here. They **may** be able to restore an account, but you may need to prepare to accept that the account is lost entirely. You can contact them via the [*contact us* form](https://stackoverflow.com/contact) or by emailing `team@stackexchange.com`.

Comment: _now browsing archive.org in search of Shog8..._

Comment: How can any of this 'remembered' information or possible account reinstatement by the SO Community Managers team be compliant with the EU's policy on account deletion?

Comment: @Cœur *Some say Shog7 came before 8 and 9. But he was banned for attempted cannibalism.*

Comment: @Jeeped Well, if you think that it conflicts with the GDPR, you should create a new Meta post for that.

Comment: @jeeped Interesting question. I assume the GPDR does not mandate that information is deleted the exact second that you click a button, generally these things work by allowing someone to request it and that request must then be honoured in a timely fashion so that would allow a grace period in which a mistake can be undone. But I am not aware of what the specific rules are about how fast you must act on a deletion request, its a good thing to have knowledge of.

Comment: @Jeeped: the problem comes with the term "data protection". By the name, "data protection" is about protecting data, not about protecting human beings. but that is bad. "data protection" should be like "privacy" and be about the protection of human beings against the mis-use of their data. It is GDPR-okay what SE does here, because basically by saving that users data they have just protected the users data against accidental deletion. The GDPR is bad, but not that bad, and you always have to read the full text. IMHO, all summaries that I found yet were pretty useless.

Comment: or maybe I'm wrong and they haven't saved it.. because the user does not seem to be restored yet :-/

Comment: Did this get fixed?

Comment: @Krease: you can check this yourself; click on the answer link in the post, it has not been connected to an active account again. I don't know if the user contacted the Community Managers team or what the outcome was if they did.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I have contacted the community. They have replied that they are looking into the problem. Its been more than a week now, there is no reply.

Answer (score 12):

The problem has been resolved by `stackoverflow` community. They have figured that accounts were merged because new user tried to login when another was already logged in, and accidentally added the credential to an existing account instead of logging into their own. This action caused the two accounts to be merged together.

At this time community have restored my posts, comments and other stuffs as well. Thanks a ton to such great community. I owe you guys.

Comment: ooh don't share computers. yikes. I must admit when I read a post of a deleted user saying their account was deleted I was intrigued.

Comment: Yeah Right. But at the end.. I got the clear reason. Thanks to the SO team :)

Comment: Welcome back! Interesting that in replying I get told you're a "new contributor" now :P

Comment: how did you fix it . Please tell me. How did you contact SO Communuity?

Comment: @depressedcoder I did post my concern in Stackoverflow meta by tagging support and with all the evidence I have. And then the moderators addresses your concern.